# Spring Actuator application properties group by status it's not working

Tags: java, spring, actuator

I'm trying to do some config at my application.properties and group by status like this:
management.endpoint.health.group.status.show-details=never

This worked with another application where the config file where a yml, and it was like this:
management:
health:
endpoints:
web:
exposure:
include: '*'
endpoint:
health:
show-details: always
group:
status:
show-details: never

How can I group by status just to show UP or DOWN when I use the /actuator/health/status endpoint?

I've tried to do the same config as the yml but with dif format:
management.endpoint.health.group.status.show-details=never